# using jquery setInterval to run x number of times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to run the setInterval method a specific number of times before cancelling it, using jquery code to start and stop this function without user intervention.

the default usage for setInterval is:

```
 <input type="button" onclick="clearInterval(timer)" value="stop">

 <script>
   var i = 1
   var timer = setInterval(function() { alert(i++) }, 2000)
 </script>
```

I would like to use this function without the button click being involved in any way

Comment: `var timer = setInterval(function () {
    alert(i++)
    if(i==10){
        clearInterval(timer);
        i = 0;
    }
}, 2000)`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aaks69Lr/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [*clearInterval*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) like bellow, It'll run the interval for 5 times & 6th time it'll clear that.

```
var i = 1;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if(i > 5)
        clearInterval(timer);
    else
        console.log(i++) 
},2000);
```